# Set password to open xls file, by Java ADF 12c

Tags: java, apache-poi, oracle-adf, xls

I have the following code to create a copy of a XLS file and protect it by setting a password to be opened.

with the listed imports:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
```

But, it just produce the same file copy without a password.
kindly advise me where is the issue.

```
            String fname = "C:\\test";
            FileInputStream fileInput = null;
            BufferedInputStream bufferInput = null;
            POIFSFileSystem poiFileSystem = null;
            FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
            try {
                fileInput = new FileInputStream(fname + ".xls");
                bufferInput = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);
                poiFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(bufferInput);
                fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fname + "_pass.xls");
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(poiFileSystem, true);
                workbook.writeProtectWorkbook("password", "AGad");
                workbook.write(fileOut);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    bufferInput.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
                try {
                    fileOut.flush();
                    fileOut.close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Comment: I found that the above code is working fine and setting a password,
the issue is that the source xls file is created by :
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
I tried it by clear xls file created by MS EXCEL.

Comment: `writeProtectWorkbook()` != <setting a password to be opened>, this is used  to block changes on a workbook ... have a look at [POIs encryption page](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)

Comment: @kiwiwings : Thank you for your reply,
but it works with me and set the password to open the file well :),
the problem with me was in the macros of the file.